# Can I limit the time a table lock is being held server side?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, locking

I have a SQL Azure server with some stored procedures with `TABLOCKX` hints that I call from C# code on a Windows Azure web role VM.

I'm kinda paranoid about those hints - what if there's some network protocol failure and the transaction doesn't end or something like that and a lock is held forever and all invokations of that stored procedure block on the statement with the `TABLOCKX` hint and all my stuff comes to a halt.

Is it somehow possible to tell SQL Server that the lock should not be held for more than say one minute so that it is unconditionally released after that time?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify using :

`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT timeout_period`

> timeout_period
>
> Is the number of milliseconds that will pass before Microsoft SQL Server returns a locking error. A value of -1 (default) indicates no time-out period (that is, wait forever).
>   When a wait for a lock exceeds the time-out value, an error is returned. A value of 0 means to not wait at all and return a message as soon as a lock is encountered.
>
> **At the beginning of a connection, this setting has a value of -1. After it is changed, the new setting stays in effect for the remainder of the connection.**
>
> The setting of SET LOCK_TIMEOUT is set at execute or run time and not at parse time.
>
> The READPAST locking hint provides an alternative to this SET option.
>
> CREATE DATABASE, ALTER DATABASE, and DROP DATABASE statements do not honor the SET LOCK_TIMEOUT setting.

Refer to : [Support for SET statements in Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336270.aspx)

UPDATE:

> Is it somehow possible to tell SQL Server that the lock should not be held for more than say one minute so that it is unconditionally released after that time?

No. As I mentioned in the comments section.

THe database wont be able to maintain its ACID properties.

Either the query fails and returns an error or the lock is held by SQL Server  until the transaction is completed and then released.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about how to limit how long a lock is *held*, not how long it is waiting to get a lock.

Comment: @ThomasStringer: Yes, exactly, I want to lock to disappear after some period of time, not the query to fail.

Comment: @sharptooth I guess that is not possible - `a lock to disappear after some period of time`. The database wont be able to maintain its ACID properties if you do that.

Comment: @sharptooth I'm not sure how you're currently implementing "everything", but most providers have a command timeout (System.Data.SqlClient's SqlCommand.ConnectionTimeout is set to 30 seconds by default).  If the query doesn't finish in that time, it'll back out just like you want.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Correct me if I am wrong, but it wont back out like OP is thinking. It will do the same thing - return an error. `SqlCommand::CommandTimeout Property` => **Gets or sets the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error.**

Comment: @ThomasStringer: Well, what if there's a connection timeout and there's a protocol error and the transaction continues in the server but the client gets an error? That's what I want to protect from.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, but you can't just release locks without completely throwing the towel in.

Comment: @sharptooth Command timeout, not connection timeout.  And you can catch specific errors that your provider lends to you.  There are ways to play with it, but I think that may be your best bet.

Comment: @Kin: Okay, I don't mind the lock disappearing and the transaction waiting for it being rolled back with error. I guess that would be ACID enough. I can sacrifice one transaction but I want the lock disappear after some time. Can I have that?

Comment: @sharptooth a command timeout would provide exactly that :-)

Comment: @ThomasStringer: If it's a server side thing how would I set it in SQL?

Comment: @sharptooth You don't.  That'd be client-side handling.

Comment: @ThomasStringer: That's the problem. If it's client side there's a chance that the server is unaware and continues having the lock held.